# issues with form/iframe based file upload in Opera

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons

### SOLUTION

Refer to my answer below: [issues with form/iframe based file upload in Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899327/issues-with-form-iframe-based-file-upload-in-opera/7936689#7936689)

---

I'm using the form/iframe technique to send files to the server whenever a browser does not support XMLHttpRequest upload (Opera). On a high level, here's the setup...

1. create an iframe `<iframe src="javascript:false;" name="file-iframe"></iframe>`
2. create a form `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`

   - set target = iframe's name, `target="file-iframe"`
   - set action = url, `action="/upload"`
3. add the file input to the form
4. submit form

When the form is submitted, the server spits out an exception:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:538)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:999)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:965)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:331)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.getItemIterator(ServletFileUpload.java:148)
    at com.beamit.jetty.UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:28)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    ...
    ...
```

Here is a code snippet in the `UploadServlet.java` file, where the failure happens in the last line of the snippet:

```
@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    ServletFileUpload up = new ServletFileUpload();
    try {
        FileItemIterator iter = up.getItemIterator(request); // <------ ERROR
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
```

I've been trying to debug this for hours and I'm getting nowhere. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

I can provide the HTTP requests for working/non-working file uploads using a different browser, as well as some more source code if needed.

### MORE INFO

HTTP request for a simple "hello world" text file in **Chrome**.

```
POST /upload/0145c HTTP/1.1
Host: beamit:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Referer: http://beamit:8080/
Content-Length: 44
Origin: http://beamit:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryQes3eWoFE2iw6kGE
```

HTTP request for a simple "hello world" text file in **Opera**.

```
POST /upload/f889b HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7.2; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52
Host: beamit:8080
Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,es;q=0.5,it;q=0.4,pt;q=0.3,pt-PT;q=0.2,nl;q=0.1,sv;q=0.1,nb;q=0.1,da;q=0.1,fi;q=0.1,ru;q=0.1,pl;q=0.1,zh-CN;q=0.1,zh-TW;q=0.1,ko;q=0.1,ar;q=0.1,cs;q=0.1,hu;q=0.1,tr;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://beamit:8080/
Cookie: __utma=248039316.1622718495.1317335167.1319648741.1319655028.19; __utmb=248039316.4.10.1319655028; __utmc=248039316; __utmz=248039316.1317335167.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------cah2BDOhbumylzxVY398ZJ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. After stripping off all unnecessary code and markup, I was left with a bare-bones form/iframe file upload page.

When I am building the form dynamically, I insert the file input element as a child:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select-input" />
```

... and I had something like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file-select-form" target="select-file-iframe" method="POST" action="/upload/">
    <div id="file-select-button" class="">
        <input type="file" id="file-select-input" />
    </div>
</form>
<iframe style="display: none" id="select-file-iframe" src="javascript:false;" name="select-file-iframe"></iframe>
```

This setup was giving me the issues. After some investigation, it turns out that when I submit the above form, the input file information was not being sent. The reason for this, it turns out, is that I didn't have the `name` attribute specified on the file input element. So when I changed it to this:

```
<input type="file" id="file-select-input" name="file" />
```

... things worked.

Comment: I found that if the URL has 'localhost' in the name then the file upload with iframe will not work in opera.  After replacing localhost with machinename it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The particular exception suggests that the client has aborted the request. I'm not sure about the exact cause, but particularly Opera is known to be troublesome with the combination iframes and JavaScript.

I would strongly recommend to grab an existing library which simulates the ajax file upload job rather than reinventing the wheel yourself. I see in your question history that you're familiar with jQuery. You could grab for example the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form) to do the best cross browser compatible magic as follows:

```html
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#formid').ajaxForm();
    });
</script>
...
<form id="formid">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can if necessary peek around in the `jquery.form.js` source [here](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js) to learn how they tackled browser specific issues.

Comment: I'm not exactly doing a file upload... I'm doing a file "stream". So I can't exactly use an existing library, but I can look at the source to figure out some things. That said, I still need to figure out why the request is broken.

Comment: I don't see how "file upload" and "file stream" are different. It's after all just a `multipart/form-data` POST request. As to the concrete problem, I'd just blame Opera.

Comment: hahaha... just blame Opera :D I agree, but that doesn't solve the issue ;) It seems like part of the problem is that the form data is not being sent when the form is submitted... `Content-Length: 76` tells me that the 2MB file I'm sending is not being sent

Comment: I'd start checking the HTTP traffic generated by different browsers with for example [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) and comparing the differences in particularly the request headers and body. If there are differences for Opera, then it (or your JS code responsible for creating the iframe's DOM) is likely to blame. Or if there are no differences, then the server side is likely to blame (which is unlikely IMHO, Commons FileUpload is pretty robust).

Comment: You can do so, but please use a simple text file with a "Hello World" line or someting instead of a 2MB and possibly binary file.

Comment: Check the update above. The `Content-Length` is still 76 for both a 2MB file and a small "Hello World" text file.

Comment: Ah, that way. Crazy Opera. How about the request body? Is the file in there? Have you tried jQuery form plugin to see if it also exhibits the same problem?

Comment: No, not yet. The request body is empty, I think.